# Disabling the "did you mean..." suggestions in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Newer versions of GCC come with what I consider to be an irritating misfeature: they try to second-guess me, emitting useless "did you mean?" suggestions that drown out other warnings.

For example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c -o /dev/null -xc - <<'EOT'
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(char *b, size_t z){ readlink("/foo", b, z); }
EOT
<stdin>: In function ‘foo’:
<stdin>:3:30: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘readlink’;
did you mean ‘realloc’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

No, I did not mean `realloc`; I just forgot to include the `unistd.h` header.

Is there any way to turn this off?

I want to have it print just `implicit declaration of function ‘readlink’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`, without the helpful suggestion.

Comment: If it turns out there is no well-defined way to disable these suggestions, I'd say a bug report / feature request to the gcc maintainers is in order.

Comment: Just `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`

Comment: @KamilCuk that will turn that warning into an error, but it won't suppress the suggestion.

Comment: This question had, until a second ago, a total grade of -1. Indicative of the tons of *conformism* raining down on this site. The question is valid and relevant. Not only because this problem would drive anyone who has to compile-fix-recompile 100s of times, to the brinks of nutness and distract them from the cause of the real problem which 99% (IMExp) lies elsewhere. It also indicates a far more systemic fault with Free, Open, Collective Software: it's been victimised from its success: the hordes of volunteers who have nothing else to do than to embelish it based on their personal aesthetics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that it's simply hardcoded and there are **no ways** to turn that off.

From the gcc [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/c/c-decl.c;h=ae0ee3a9c9606a8009c2b60767c5227cd6671043;hb=0c0b297d68848fd6812aa59651fe7b039ed6f4ef#l3297):

```
3328       warned = warning_at
3329         (&richloc, OPT_Wimplicit_function_declaration,
3330          G_("implicit declaration of function %qE; did you mean %qs?"),
3331          id, suggestion);
```

[And no, neither `lookup_name_fuzzy()` nor `hint.suggestion ()` will take any command line option into consideration when returning their results]

Filtering the error output with some shell sorcery, eg. with

```
{ gcc ... 2>&1 >&3 | sed 's/; did you mean [^?]*[?]//' >&2; } 3>&1
```

is not really a solution, first because it cannot be used in makefiles (the error status of the command line will be that of the `sed` or whatever filter, not that of gcc), and second because it will still leave around things like:

```
 void foo(char *b, size_t z){ readlink("/foo", b, z); }
                              ^~~~~~~~
                              realloc
```

which will need some complicated logic to filter out.

[using bash/kshisms like `2> >(...)` won't help with the 1st point either, because `make` will use `/bin/sh`, not the user's shell]

Answer (score 1):

Just a little addition to the solution by @ImpudentSnob, to filter out those suggestion lines as well:

1. Find your gcc, like in my case: `~/.espressif/.../xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc`
2. Rename it by adding '.didyoumean' to the end of the name, like `xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.didyoumean`
3. Put this script there, with the original gcc name:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail
{ $0.didyoumean "$@" 2>&1 >&3 | awk '{if (sub("; did you mean [^?]*[?]", "")) cnt=4} (cnt!=1){print} (cnt>0){cnt--}' >&2;} 3>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution within `gcc` except for making your own modification. A non-optimal solution is piping into `sed`.

```
gcc main.c 2>&1 | sed -E "s/; did you mean .*\?//"
```

What I'm doing here is redirecting `stderr` (where the warnings are printed) to `stdout` with `2>&1` and then I made a simple replace script that removes that phrase.

It adds some complexity, and you lose the colours, but it does what you asked for.

Comment: Consider `gcc ... 2> >(sed ... >&2)` to filter only stderr, and emit the filtered results *back* to the original program's stderr. (Not that the approach is unambiguously better -- sending stdout and stderr to different sinks means that there's no longer a well-defined ordering of writes between them).

Comment: @SteveSummit Tbh, I have always used it without knowing what it's for. :D

Comment: @SteveSummit I have removed the modifier now after testing it. Comment cleanup.